# why text changed is not reflected to viewmodel property

Tags: nativescript

I have a property `name`

```
var viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({
    name: "abcd",
    onUsernameChanged: function () {
      console.log("-->"+ viewModel.name)
    }
  });
```

textfield like below,

```
<TextField text="{{name}}" textChange="{{ onUsernameChanged }}"
                class="h2 description-label" />
```

When I change the text by typing, It always prints `--->abcd` only.

Why the viewmodel property is not updated ?

[Playground Demo of problem](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=jaGIxm)

*currently I'm reading the changed text like below, And this method is not flexible and easy to use like viewmodel*

```
var view = require("ui/core/view");
var idUsername = view.getViewById(args.object, "idUsername");
```

Answer (score 0):

By taking a look at your code, I am inferring that **there is no binding between your view** (the XML file containing the `TextField`—assuming you are using *NativeScript Core*) **and your view-model** (the javascript file where you have your observable `viewModel`).

When the `textChange` event emits, you are printing the **stored value** at your ViewModel over and over (`name`, in this case: `abcd`). For example, at first, your value is `abcd`, but the text might be empty. Later, you type `A`, and then it prints `abcd` again, and so on.

**If you want to print the new text output TextField element**, you have to use the output emitted by the event. Look at this excerpt:

```js
const viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({
  name: "abcd",
  onUsernameChanged: function (eventData) {
    // eventData has information on the textChange event
    console.dir(eventData);
    // Do whatever you want with this data, such as updating the view model
  }
});
```

Comment: If I have a form with 50 text fields. And then I want to use the newly entered value, your solution will be a bad idea. Think, how many on change event I need to write ? as i mentioned`getViewById` will work fine. But I need a data observing thing ! (as per my knowledge Viewmodel is all about binding and observing right). I'm expecting that to ease my work.

Comment: You didn't say that in your question at all. Give us more context to give you a more proper solution. My approach solves your `why text changed is not reflected to ViewModel property?` question.

Comment: Ok, what you mean by binding. can you show exactly how to do that for the `textfield`. I thought I did binding as per the docs. But, you are saying it is not binded. I'm confused with your statement I need example.

Answer (score 0):

try using **this.get()**

```
console.log("-->"+ this.get('name'))
```